# __stdcall without any decoration

Tags: windows, dll, calling-convention, build-tools, stdcall

I have a `.dll` I suspect uses `__stdcall` functions, but *totally* undecorated names (not even an underscore or `@` sign). I wrote a `.def` file for it with aliases like

```
func1 = func1
func1@4 = func1
```

but I think `lib` (which I am using to create the import library from the `.def` file) is ignoring the aliases (the linker still says `func1@4` is undefined)

How can I create an import library that will map `func1@4` to `func1`?

Comment: The syntax in your exports file looks incorrect. Check with dumpbin.exe to be sure. Usually each line only needs to contain the name you wish the function to have (e.g `func1`) and the linker will figure out the details itself.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it possible to create right `.lib` file with `lib.exe`, so I suggest to create a DLL with stubs of functions exported by original DLL.

Example `dll.cpp` file:

```
void __stdcall foo(int) {}
```

`dll.def` file:

```
EXPORTS
foo=foo
```

Then you compile it, from IDE, or command line:

```
cl dll.cpp /link /dll /def:dll.def /noentry
```

It will create correct `dll.lib` file, so you can use it with code like this:

```
void __stdcall foo(int);
#pragma comment(lib, "dll")
int main()
{
    foo(42);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be declaring the function prototype as extern "C" as you are (obviously) compiling with in C++ mode:

```
extern "C" void func1(void); // correct prototype, add __stdcall if necessary?
```

You can wrap entire sections of a header file inside

```
extern "C" {
    // ... C compatible declarations
}
```

Comment: I am using `extern "c"`. On it's own it changes it to `__cdecl`. When I add `__stdcall` I get a `@` added.

Comment: @baruch perhaps you could show us the code. FWIW, I don't think the problem is in the def file

Comment: @baruch well then... try the other code? Quote "the linker says func1@4 is undefined" i.e. the problem is in your code. You are referring to `func1@4` instead of `func1` so your header ---is wrong--- doesn't match the lib

Comment: That is the question? How do I tell it that `func1` should be linked as `func1` but still use the __stdcall convention?

Comment: @baruch Well, if the export is names `func1` that would lead me to believe that it _isn't_ in fact __stdcall then. I'll remove my unhelpful answer in a few minutes.